# ¿Cómo guardar información respectivamente en cada array de un ciclo for en una entrada por teclado?

Tags: java, array, loops, entrada

tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un pequeño programa en donde la computadora te pide que ingreses los nombres, edades y estaturas de 5 individuos.

**Como son 5 individuos, decidí crear arrays para las variables:**

```
for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){

        System.out.println("\nIndividuo " +i);
        System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre: ");
        nombres [0] = Entrada.cadena();
        System.out.println("Introduce tu edad: ");
        edades [0] = Entrada.entero();
        System.out.println("Introduce tu estatura: ");
        estaturas[0] = Entrada.real();
```

Lo que quiero es que, cuando pase al siguiente individuo, pida en la entrada por teclado el siguiente array vacío, hasta llegar a 5 como lo indico en el ciclo.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la información de cada individuo sea guardada en su respectivo espacio del array en sólo 1 ciclo for?

Comment: Sabes algo de programación orientada a objetos?

Comment: Sinceramente no mucho, soy nuevo en Java, no tendría problema si me explicas puedo entender :)

Comment: Así, muy resumido, consiste en crear objetos de un tipo en los que guardas información. Mira a ver si esto te ayuda https://prezi.com/mwu96ooe0quh/primeros-pasos-en-programacion-orientada-a-objetos/ .  De todas formas con la solución que te puse debería valer.

Comment: Me sale esto: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at EjercicioAlterno.main(EjercicioAlterno.java:26)

Comment: Inicializa la i en 0 y pon como condición del for que sea < 5, porque si no llegará un momento que te acceda a la posición 5 y no la tienes.

Comment: Como dice @G3l0, los arrays en java son 0-based, es decir, sus indices comienzan en 0 y llegan hasta el tamaño-1

Comment: Gracias @G3I0, el programa me corrió como quería. Saludos :)

Comment: Y como consejo, deberías mirarte la POO porque es mucho más práctico que hacerlo como lo tienes. Un saludo amigo.

Comment: Le puse así: for (int i=0,ind=1;i<5;i++,ind++){
   
   System.out.println("\nIndividuo " +ind);
   System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre: ");
   nombres [i] = Entrada.cadena();
   System.out.println("Introduce tu edad: ");
   edades [i] = Entrada.entero();
   System.out.println("Introduce tu estatura: ");
   estaturas [i] = Entrada.real();

Comment: Es para que Individuo también tenga su contador, así diga individuo 1 y 2 y así. Si amigo ya voy a ver el link que me enviaste

Comment: No entiendo el ind, si es para coger el número del individuo, con usar la i te vale. Usa i + 1 para el individuo y así no tienes dos contadores

Comment: Supondría que sólo cambió el "i = 0" a "i = 1" y ponerle menor que 6...Verdad? .-. Jajajaja

Comment: Me refiero que donde haces `System.out.println("\nIndividuo " +ind);` pongas `System.out.println("\nIndividuo " +(i + 1)); `, pero lo que tu dices también vale aunque a mi gusto queda peor xD

Comment: Esa no la sabía Jajajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de `array[0]` usa `array[i]`. De esta forma te cogerá el índice dinámicamente. Y el `for` constrúyelo así `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`.